# performance of string.tolowercase on a lower case string

Tags: java, string, performance

I want to know the implications of the `toLowerCase` on a String. The string here can vary in length up to 50 chars and can be a lower case also.

In our case, We need to check for the string which in entered by user and then saving that input, in lower case, in database and its to be checked on a large volume.

So should I check for the case mismatch first and then apply the `String.toLowerCase` OR directly always apply the `String.toLowerCase()` on every string including lower case strings.

Is there any better way to handle such type of situations keeping performance in mind?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Openjdk performs a check internally whether there are any non-lowercase characters before starting to build a new string:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.toLowerCase%28java.util.Locale%29

SUN Java works in a similar way (see comment below), so there is no need for your own extra check.

---

You should be able to double-check (in a small test program) with `==` whether your version of Java allocates a new string even if not necessary:

```
String test = "all lower case";
if (test == test.toLowerCase()) {
  System.out.println("The strings are the same object, " + 
      "so toLowerCase performs a check before allocating a new one.");
} else {
  System.out.println("A new string object is created even when not needed.");
}
```

Comment: I'd give you a +1 for posting the link for the source, but your last part makes no sense. He's trying to **avoid** calling `toLowerCase()` and you call it right there...

Comment: Clarified in the text that the toLowerCase experiment is to figure out what the library actually does.

Comment: Better now :) But i'd still put a "----" after that SUN line. Btw, I checked, and Sun's (Oracle's) JRE implements pretty much like OpenJDK.

Answer (score 4):

In my career, I had to work on parsing some huge files (>1GB after deflating). From my experience it is a good idea to directly call `toLowercase()` instead of doing a check and then calling it.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to check the upper ones you'll have to perform `for loop + if condition` and that is so ugly so I think it's good to go with `toLowercase()` direcly for all strings + `toLowercase()` actually perform these actions for you

Answer (score 2):

String.toLowerCase is optimized to create a new String only when necessary, try this

```
    String s = "date";
    System.out.print(s == s.toLowerCase());
```

output

```
true
```

Comment: Read the question to end :)

Answer (score 1):

I think allowing database to do the conversion  using trigger may be a better in performance than doing string manipulation in java. I have not tested this but you may try to see whether there is a performance difference.

Define [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) on the table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER lcase_insert BEFORE INSERT ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.language = LOWER(NEW.language);

CREATE TRIGGER lcase_update BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.language = LOWER(NEW.language);
```